# Hide Master Details View Controller on Selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, master-detail

I have been looking for a away to hide the master details when I select a cell.
I couldn't find any straight forward answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:barButtonItem.action to:barButtonItem.target from:nil forEvent:nil];
```